# object is null when passed to service in angularjs using $resource

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I have been working on it from last couple of hours but not getting on my way.Thanks for any help in advance.

My contract code:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "Employee", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
[OperationContract]
void PutEmployeeAccount(Employee obj);
```

My service code

```
public void PutEmployeeAccount(Employee obj)
{
//  obj passed is null
}
```

My AngularJS Code

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);
myApp.factory('resourceService', function ($resource) {

var src = $resource("../EmployeeService.svc/Employee/:id",
{ id: "@id" },           //parameters default
{
GetData: { method: "GET", params: {}, isArray: true },
GetDataById: { method: "GET", params: { id: 0 }, isArray: true },
Delete: { method: "DELETE", params: { id: 0 }, isArray: true },
Update: { method: "PUT", params: {}, isArray: true },
save: { method: "PUT", params: {}, isArray: false }
});
return src;
});

function EmployeeCtrl($scope, resourceService) {
var Employee = new resourceService();
Employee.Employeename = 'bar';
Employee.$save();
}
```

Calling web service is OK for PutEmployeeAccount.But the object of employee passed is null
How can I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved by hit and trial,setting BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare has solved the issue.

Comment: Good for you! You can also accept your own answers, so that others see that the question is resolved.